# Passagem por referência de objeto Wrapper para método

Tags: java, variáveis, passagem-por-referência

Estive pesquisando sobre passagem por referência em Java e percebi que não é possível realizar, diretamente, esse procedimento. Como apenas referências de objetos e array's podem ser passadas por referência pensei em usar as classes Wrapper para resolver problemas em que preciso alterar um inteiro, por exemplo, que esteja no main utilizando um método. Fiz diversos testes mas a alteração nunca é feita adequadamente. Onde estou errando? E qual seria uma forma alternativa de resolver o meu problema? 
Segue o código que eu fiz para realizar esses testes.

```
public class ReferenciaTeste {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Integer k = new Integer(1);

        System.out.println(k.toString()); //anterior à passagem

        ReferenciaTeste.muda(k);

        System.out.println(k.toString()); //depois da passagem

    }
}


public static void muda(Integer n)
{
    n = 3;
}
```

Saída:

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## O que aconteceu

O que acontece logicamente após a primeira atribuição é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não importa que você usou `new Integer(1)` ou simplesmente `1`, o resultado é o mesmo.

Quando você chamou o método `muda`, o que ocorre é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E, finalmente, quando ocorre a segunda atribuição, temos um novo valor para `n`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o método `muda` acaba, a variável `n` e o valor `3` são descartados e o estado continue o mesmo da primeira imagem.

## O que acontece com um array

Ao usar um array, na verdade você está referenciando um objeto que contém vários valores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao passar isso para o método `muda`, você terá duas variáveis apontando para o array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao mudar um elemento, as duas variáveis permanecem apontando para o mesmo array, porém o estado interno do array é afetado, mudando um dos seus valores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Finalmente, após a execução do método, a variável `k` permanece intacta e inalterada, contudo, o estado interno do objeto que ela referencia foi afetado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Usando um objeto wrapper

A resposta do DannE diz como você pode usar um objeto cujo valor interno pode ser afetado.

Não vou desenhar isso porque seria exatamente a mesma sequência usando o vetor.

Na verdade, muitas pessoas usam vetores ou mapas como uma forma fácil de modificar parâmetros, mas isso não chega a ser muito comum nem boa prática.

## Considerações

Objetos imutáveis como `Integer` e `String` e referências que não podem ser afetadas nos métodos (como ponteiros de ponteiros em C) existem por uma razão muito simples: **manter a sanidade mental dos desenvolvedores**.

Digo isso porque embora deixe a linguagem mais restrita, isso também evita inúmeros problemas onde valores são inesperadamente modificados por métodos obscuros. Numa linguagem que pretende ser fácil e universal, este é um pequeno preço a se pagar.

Além disso, a solução básica para este caso é extremamente simples. Basta retornar o objeto modificado:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Integer k = 1;
    Integer k1 = incrementa2(k);
    System.out.println(k1); 
}

public static Integer incrementa2(Integer n) {
    return n + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicando detalhadamente seu problema:

1 - Quando você cria o objeto `k`, você aloca na memória um objeto que referencia este `Integer`.
2 - Quando você chama o método `muda(Integer n)`, você está declarando um `Integer` **no método `muda`**. O que isto quer dizer? Quer dizer que, ao passar a variável `k` como parâmetro deste método, os dois (`k` e `n`) estarão referenciando o mesmo objeto na memória.
3 - O problema é: a partir do momento que você muda o valor da variável `n`, esta variável deixa de referenciar o mesmo objeto da variável `k`, referenciando um novo objeto `Integer` de valor, no seu caso, `3`.


Resumindo, qualquer mudança que você fizer no `Integer` declarado **dentro** do método `muda(Integer n)` somente terá efeito neste mesmo método, não influenciando no objeto externo que foi passado como parâmetro.

**Como resolver**
Crie uma classe chamada, por exemplo, `IntegerWrapper` e crie um objeto do tipo `Integer`, e adicione seus getters e setters. Desse modo, você sempre estará utilizando o mesmo objeto em suas mudanças.
Um exemplo de como poderia ser este Wrapper:

```
public class IntegerWrapper {
    private Integer i;

    public void setValue(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não compreendi porque uma alteração na variável "n" vai acarretar em deixar de referenciar o mesmo local de memória que a variável "k" refere. Quando utilizo um array, por exemplo, e faço alterações nele, essas alterações acontecem no mesmo local da memória e assim eu obtenho o array modificado no main().

Comment: Porque você não está alterando a variável `n`, e sim criando uma nova instância dela. Sempre que você utiliza o `=` para definir um valor para uma variável, você estará criando uma nova instância dela. Instância essa que só é válida para o escopo atual. Normalmente alteramos arrays em outro método trocando alguma posição dele, o que é permitido pois estamos usando a mesma instância, mas se você tentar definir um novo array utilizando o `=`, verá que o mesmo permanecerá inalterado ao sair do método em que você definiu esse novo array.

Comment: Realizei um rápido teste para comprovar. Criei um vetor de inteiros (`int[]`) e populei com 20 valores. Após isso, passei este vetor como parâmetro para um método e alterei o valor do índice 19 deste modo: `inteiros[19] = valor;`, o que funciona. Logo após, alterei este método e criei um novo vetor desse modo: `inteiros = new int[20];`, e, nesse caso, o vetor permaneceu inalterado ao retornar para o método `main`.