# Funcionamento das variáveis por referência

Tags: java, referência

Sei que as variáveis por referência em java servem para proporcionar uma localização em memória de certo objeto. Entretanto, como esse mecanismo funciona? É igual à linguagem C, onde os tipos por referência guardam exatamente o endereço de memória do que se deseja localizar?

Comment: Exato. As variáveis por referência apenas apontam um endereço na memória. A grosso modo, são aliases (atalhos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser ter uma ideia de como funcionam as referências durante a criação de um objeto e quando você passada uma referência por parâmetro, sugiro dar uma olhada na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99401/227) à pergunta [*Passagem por referência de objeto Wrapper para método*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99381/227).

Basicamente, fazendo isso:

```
Integer k = new Integer(1);
```

Você declara uma variável e atribui uma nova instância a ela. Uma possível representação seria:

[image: Variável apontando para objeto]

Podemos dizer que `k` é uma variável que referencia o objeto do tipo `Integer` cujo valor interno é `1`.

Até agora nada diferente de um ponteiro em C referenciando uma estrutura em memória. Entretanto, a diferença do Java fica evidente quando você pensa no que você pode fazer com essa referência.

Em C você está literalmente referenciando a memória e pode inclusive realizar operações com o ponteiro, tal como `p++` para avançar para a próxima posição na memória. Você pode também acessar os bytes desse objeto desconsiderando o conteúdo.

Em Java, por outro lado, variáveis que referenciam objetos são apenas meios para acessar tais objetos e não podem ser usadas como referências genéricas a posições de memória, nem para modificar esses objetos diretamente.

Basicamente, tudo o que uma referência pode fazer é acessar membros, atributos e métodos, dos objetos em questão.

Answer (score 3):

Quando vc cria um objeto do tipo Animal por exemplo, com o comando `new Animal();` o objeto dessa classe está sendo criado neste momento, mas para manipular as informações do "Animal" você precisa de uma variavél de referencia que é justamente a variável que guarda o endereço de memória do objeto instanciado. Por isso geralmente se faz assim `Animal animal = new Animal();` onde animal é variável de referência que guarda o endereço de memória do objeto, mas geralmente essa variável de referência é chamada de objeto. Um fato que as vezes confunde um pouco quem está começando a estudar java é achar que existe passagem de parâmetros por valor e por referência, quando na verdade a passagem de parâmetros em java sempre é por valor. Esse engano se dá pelo fato de que quando um objeto é passado como parâmetro, o que está sendo passado é na verdade sua variável de referência (Que tem como conteúdo um endereço de memória) mas ainda sim o que está sendo passado é apenas uma cópia do conteúdo da variável e não uma referência a ela. Esse site mostra de maneira bem didática como isso acontece http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp