# Qual a diferença de float e float[]?

Tags: java, array, float

Estou a ver uns códigos que uns exercícios aqui no site e sempre que vejo alguma coisa que não entenda, pesquiso.

No caso agora foi em relação ao `float[]` ,

Qual é a real diferença entre esse tipo de determinação e o simples `float`?

Comment: Isso é um array de floats, ou seja, como uma variavel com diversos valores do mesmo tipo, float.

Comment: Através  do seu comentário não percebi bem o que é uma array, mas pelo menos já sei o que é, depois disso irei estudar mais sobre tal tema.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: É isso, uma "variavel" que aceita diversos valores de um mesmo tipo, no caso float[] vai aceitar algo como `float[] x = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 1.2 };`, já float só um valor `float y = 2.5;`

Comment: Então ao invés de no caso, criar 5 variáveis, crio somente uma?

Comment: Se for SUA intenção sim, tipo tiver quantidade de valores indeterminados ou até tratar/comparar variados valores do mesmo tipo para saber qual o maior, supondo que receba vários floats, você quer saber qual é o maior, qual é o menor, qual está na média. Um dos usos de um vetor ao invés de diversas variáveis é justamente poder ter uma quantidade de valores "indeterminados". Claro que haverá momentos que poderá ter a intenção de usar multidimensional, algo como `float[][]`, `float[][][]`, etc.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

O tipo `float` é um tipo de dado numérico que guarda valores de várias grandezas e precisão na parte decimal bem abrangente, então pode guardar valores muito grandes e bastante fracionados. Ao contrário do que muitos pensam, eles não possuem exatidão, ele não pode representar todos os números, ele depende de aproximações, mas para certos problema isto não é problema, é [quando se trata de valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Apesar dele ter uma parte decimal, o chamamos de valor de ponto flutuante binário já que sua representação é binária, por isso não tem exatidão.

O `float[]` está indicando que você tem um vetor de dados `float`s. Então ali terá uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) que será composta por diversas variáveis indexadas numericamente para acessar cada elemento. E cada um desses elementos é um dado do tipo `float`. Esta é a sintaxe para declarar um dado como um [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101) de `float`s. Veja também [Quais as aplicações de arrays no dia a dia? (exemplos da sua usabilidade)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250505/101).

Você declara uma variável assim:

```
float notas[] = new float[5];
```

Java aceita assim também e algumas preferem porque é mais simétrico, que é o que deve ter visto:

```
float[] notas = new float[5];
```

Note que usa os colchetes sem um valor apenas na variável, quando usamos com o tipo estamos inicializando o *array* e por isso precisamos colocar um valor ali para dizer o tamanho do *array*. Sem um valor dá erro e não compila. Esse valor pode ser fixo ou variável (só conhecido no momento de criar o *array*), mas depois do *array* ser criado ele não pode mais mudar de tamanho, por isso em muitos casos as pessoas preferem criar um `ArrayList` que permite isso, aí muda tudo:

```
List<float> notas = new ArrayList<float>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/ScalarXArray.java).

Não vou dar mais detalhes porque os *links* já respondem com muito mais propriedade e não faz sentido escrever aqui de novo.

Comment: Transcrevendo a resposta a cima. 
"Através do seu comentário não percebi bem o que é uma array, mas pelo menos já sei o que é, depois disso irei estudar mais sobre tal tema.   Muito obrigado."

Answer (score 1):

O `float` é um tipo primitivo de números decimais em *Java*, exemplo: `1.234`,`5.7`,`19.3456999`. Note que os números decimais em *Java* e em outras linguagens não possuem vírgula (,) e sim um ponto. No mundo da programação chamamos esses tipos de números de valores de **Ponto Flutuante**, e daí veio o nome **float**.

O `float[]` é um [array](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranjo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) (conjunto de variáveis) unidimensional do tipo `float`. Em Java você só pode guardar valores que sejam do mesmo tipo do array, neste caso, você só poderá guardar valores do tipo *float*.

## Inicializando um array:

Existem várias formas de se inicializar um array em Java, mas a forma mais básica é utilizando `new tipo[tamanho]`. Note que você pode inicializar arrays de diversos tipos de valores pois os colchetes informam que a sua variável guardará um array. O correto neste caso, é dizer que a [variável de referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102403/funcionamento-das-vari%C3%A1veis-por-refer%C3%AAncia) guardará um array. Veja este exemplo:

```
String myArray[] = new String[5]; // O array guardará 5 valores no máximo do tipo String.
```

*E se eu apenas escrever `float[] myArray;` no meu código ?* 
Nesse caso você estará apenas criando uma referência mas não o array em si.

## Array multidimensional:

Alguma hora você poderá encontrar também o seguinte código:

```
float[][] myArray = new float[tamanho][tamanho];
```

*Espera aí... dois colchetes ? Whaaat ?!*

Para sua surpresa, podem haver um, dois ou mais colchetes. Mais de um colchete significa que o array não é mais unidimensional e sim multidimensional. Isso quer dizer que dentro de um array existem outros arrays. Veja o código abaixo:

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] nomes = new String[2][2];
        nomes[0][0] = "Maria";
        nomes[0][1] = "João";
        nomes[1][0] = "Lucas";
        nomes[1][1] = "Larissa";

        for (int y = 0; y <2;y++) {
            System.out.println("Este é o id da posição "+y+" do array: "+nomes[y]);
            for (int x = 0; x<2;x++) {
                System.out.println(nomes[y][x]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O `float` é um tipo primitivo de um número com decimais, exemplo: 1.6 (1,6 na lingua BR).
O `float[]` é um conjunto de variáveis (array unidimensional) do tipo float, ou seja vários números com decimais em uma "caixa" [1.6, 1.0, 3.2]. Esses números dentro de uma "caixa" nós também chamamos conceitualmente de vetor.

Obs.: É possível também haver caixas dentro de caixas float[][], neste caso chamamos conceitualmente arrays bidimensionais, ou matrizes.

Lembrando que o java possui uma classe chamada Arrays (java.utils.) que possui diversos métodos que auxiliam na manipulação de arrays.

Comment: Em Java, vetor é o mesmo que *array*? E um *array* de *array* é o mesmo que matriz? Tem certeza disso?

Comment: Oh, Perdão, explanei de forma incorreta, irei editar. Obrigado por informar.